# How to learn about hydrogen fuel cells

Tags: hydrogen

Problem: I am a physics and engineering major going to work for an engineering company this summer. My boss wants me to do a comprehensive review of hydrogen fuel cells and report back on the cutting-edge advancements and potential future advances. I tried checking out some papers on hydrogen fuel cells on the web of science, but there are more words I don't understand than ones I do.

Question: What chemistry should I learn to understand hydrogen fuel cells better? (I have taken one college chemistry class) Obviously, I can't become a chemist in a few months, but I'm wondering if it is possible to learn enough to understand what others are doing from an abstract level.

Any advice is welcome including books, papers, or telling me to give up!

Comment: I'd suggest to open relevant Wikipedia page and look at the References and Categories sections at the very bottom.

Comment: You don't have a sufficient background in chemistry and material science to do a worthwhile job. I suggest talking with your boss upfront before starting this too ambitious project and be sure that appropriate expectations are set.

Answer (score 2):

I would familiarize myself with and master the following:

- The actual concepts of oxidation and reduction (OIL RIG - Oxidation Is Loss, Reduction Is Gain of electrons)
- The electrochemical series
  Which metals are more and less prone to oxidation/reduction than hydrogen
- Half equations using electrons
- The Galvanic cell and electrolytes
- Electrolysis of water (without sodium chloride)
- Hydrogen fuel cell concept
- More advanced details like membranes, electrolytes, materials for electrodes etc.

Dedication to the topic should see you up and running in less than a month.
I'm no expert, but it sounds like you need enough electrochemistry to get going. A good introductory book (although not right up to date) is Understanding Batteries by the Royal Society of Chemistry. Not a page tuner by any means, but has the basics.
Other sources are any search for electrochemical hydrogen fuel cell.
Good luck.